# In android I wanted to dismiss the dialog box when user comes from setting app

Tags: android

I want to dismiss the dialog box when user comes from setting app.

This is my onCreate function

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        checkLocationService(); 

}
```

This function user for checking location service is on or off.

```
private void checkLocationService(){
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        try {
            gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG,ex.toString());
        }

        if(!gps_enabled){
            showSettingsAlert();
        }

    }
```

This function is for showing an alert dialog box.

```
private void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing the Settings button.
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivityForResult(intent,SETTING_INTENT_REQUEST);

            }
        });

        // On pressing the cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==SETTING_INTENT_REQUEST){
            setAlarm();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This does dismiss before you are going to Location Settings right?

Comment: So what is the problem exactly? I can see `dialog.dismiss();` besides the code that opens up settings...

Comment: This code dismiss the dialog as you click on settings button of alert dialog,dismiss and then going to settings activity.Then what exaclty your problem

Comment: But when return from setting to my application. Dialog not dismiss its already open

Comment: do you have any alert dialog related code in setAlarm method

Comment: No @BasheerKohli no alert dialog method inside setAlarm

Comment: instead of this you can use googleapiclient which helpfull to show location setttings popup with in the application which is user specified as of my point.

Comment: Okay @BasheerKohli I'll try according to your suggestion

Comment: @JagjeetSingh : Check my answer!

Answer (score 1):

There is no dismiss() method of `AlertDialog.Builder` instance. So instead of `AlertDialog.Builder` use `AlertDialog` instance as per below :

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
```

Then you could apply dismiss function using `alertDialog.dismiss();`

Comment: @Vyacheslav : Thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you. You want to cancel alert inside callback:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==SETTING_INTENT_REQUEST){
if (alert != null && alert.isShowing()) {
alert.dismiss();
}
            setAlarm();
        }
    }
```

And, of course, use this:

```
     AlertDialog alert ;
    private void showSettingsAlert() {
            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
/// setup your builder here

///....
AlertDialog alert =  alertDialog.create();
```

Comment: there is no dismiss() method with AlertDialog.Builder instance

Comment: @Jai , ok fixed

Comment: Again no need to dismiss it again inside onActivityResult :)

Comment: @Jai , honestly, I found some cases when this alert dialog pipeline worked incorrect. Imo, for old devices better to implement this